# pattern for handling "database" of instances

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

for my application I am loading from the hardrive a list of different "items": these "items" are plain-old-data structs and represent the definitive list of all the "items" in my program.
So far what I do is that I simply put all the deserialized instances into one big std::vector and refer to them in the rest of my program by pointers. I am not supposed to have any "item" object anywhere else than in my std::vector that acts as a database.
Is there a good or specific design pattern for this case? I feel like sooner or later I will have item objects elsewhere than in my std::vector or that i'm using a method that is too simple to be robust
thanks

edit : for clarification's sake, I am doing something like this (from memory):

```
struct Item {
    std::string name;
    int property; //etc
}

class Items {

static std::vector<Item> _list;

static void init() {

    Item new_item = readfromfile(...);
    _list.push_back(new_item)

}

}
```

Comment: Based on your edit your closest resemblance to a design pattern might be a singleton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are passing pointers around, a `std::vector` is a bad idea because the pointer will change when the vector needs to be reallocated. Consider using `boost::ptr_vector` and dynamic allocation.

Apart from this minor consideration, a simple vector is the simplest storage possible and as good as any other when iteration is the only concern. I'd advise you to stay with it until other needs arise.

Comment: I don't reallocate my vector after initialisation though

Comment: @lezebulon: So you never add, remove, or move items in this vector?

Comment: I am adding items during the init() call where I push the elements I read from a file. Then... that's it, I don't add/delete any items at runtime

Comment: @lezebulon: You might be alright then. The warning thiton was giving was that various things can cause a `std::vector` to need to grow or move it's elements in which case any pointers or iterators to elements you were using become invalid.